# How to create a shopify fulfillment for an order using the REST API library in the Shopify react app?

Tags: javascript, rest, shopify, fulfillment

In the official Shopify REST API documentation i am unable to find an API which can create a fulfillment for an order(s). Any idea how to get through this?

I have tried playing around with the Order, Fulfillment, FulfillmentOrder classes but have found no success so far. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You do not create Fulfillments. Instead, Shopify creates FulfillmentOrders. You read those, and do as you need to do. So you can add tracking numbers and make partial fulfillments, etc, all by manipulating FulfillmentOrders. Not sure what you mean when you say you tried FulfillmentOrder calls, but that is what it is. Fulfillments can be hard to wrap your head around but they work. Note that the GraphQL calls are probably easier, so you probably want to drop using RestAPI and instead focus your efforts on the GraphQL fulfillment library.